# Identifying objects within a group by something that's not a name

Tags: information-architecture

I'm stuck with a rather odd information architecture that I'm trying to untangle in a crowd computing platform. Essentially, my platform has the concept of a "Use Case" - a task definition containing tasty things like settings, instructions, and so forth. A user can create an unlimited amount of "Jobs" out of these Use Cases, and launch those jobs into the crowd.

The user then can go and see a list of Jobs and their statuses within a particular Use Case. But when the user opens a specific Job, it's currently called the same thing as the Use Case at the top of the page. This has created a lot of confusion, where users can't figure out the difference between a Use Case and a Job.

One way I want to help clear this up is to identify the Jobs by a *different name* than the Use Case. To use an analogy, if I print out 50 copies of the same photo of Justin Timberlake, I can refer to each individual piece of paper as page 1, page 2, etc. But referring to them by number will be very difficult, because we might be looking at hundreds of thousands of Jobs for any given Use Case.

Comment: Is it possible to use more specific names for each 'job'? Something that might be a little more descriptive for the user based on the settings they've set? I take it that each job that comes from a use case is slightly different from one another?

Comment: @bretteast No, each job is identical settings-wise. It has different data and results but that's it. More like a batch, really.

Comment: Is this actually to do with photography? Would the industry accepted "contact sheet" or "contact sheet for Justin Timberlake" work?

Comment: @DarrylGodden It's a cool idea, but sadly we couldn't be further from photography.

Comment: do i have this right? a job is composed of a series of use cases; each use case displays which jobs it is part of. if so, would "task" and "task group" work as explicit labels? if one composes the other i think it's simpler to express that relationship somewhere. edit: rereading the last paragraph it seems distinguishing between jobs is also a problem? in which case there must be something that makes each unique - time created, creator name, reward amount, etc?

Answer (score 1):

> But referring to them by number will be very difficult, because we might be looking at hundreds of thousands of Jobs for any given Use Case.

This problem has nothing to do with numbers, or names for that matter. The difficulty is cognitive load due to a large volume of options, not the reference used to identify the options.

I think having the user name each job is a bad idea, since they will struggle to find a name that is unique given that each job is largely identical. Especially, if they create jobs frequently.

I think the system should automatically label each job with a sequence number. This way, the user can compare jobs by sequence number and get some information about when the job was run. You would need to highlight what use case was used to create the job but make sure this appears as secondary information. A tag to the left of the sequence number might be your best bet.

To deal with the large volume of jobs created you should help the user sort through their jobs by highlighting metadata they will easily recall. Since the sequence number will not reveal much about the particular job. For example, the date and time a job was created would be facts about the job the user might recall. You can list the jobs in groups based on metadata e.g. date created, or provide filters based on the metadata.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - Date + Username worked well with existing users because it didn't add any new work, just made the existing metadata more visible. Users received the idea of sequence numbers very poorly, though.

Comment: I see. @SPavel any idea why they didn't support sequence numbers? Or was it that they didn't approve of sequence numbers being used without any secondary metadata?

Comment: I suspect it was because each Job is already overloaded with all kinds of data. Users didn't want another parameter taking up real estate. There *is* a UUID for each Job to refer to it programmatically, and developers liked that I added it in an expandable section, but those things are not really human-readable (16-digit alphanumeric code).

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you need to give people a way to name jobs - and possibly number them with some sort of unique identifier - and label or title it in the most uniquely identifiable way, while keeping them grouped within their Use Cases.

For example, say the Use Case was "Create an Account" and one job was "View help, and perhaps there are seven other View Help jobs in the use case of which this is number 5 (who knows why, I'm just basic it on my extrapolation of your situation). You might title each job something like **"View Help v5 [Create an Account]"**

This puts what seems to be the **most immediately relevant piece of information first**, but allows for iteration and includes the name of the "parent" Use Case. This is a very first pass, but does this address some of what you are referencing? How are these things organized and displayed in your system now?

Comment: Sorry if it didn't come across - all jobs are identical, aside from the data that workers will work on. "Create an account" in your example would be its own Use Case, with a job for each time someone sent in a request to create an account.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty straightforward parent/child relationship, where the parent can create as many identical children as required. The issue is one of language.

Can you draw on a stronger real-world analogy for the relationship between use cases and jobs?

- chicken and egg
- factory and product
- tree and leaf
- galaxy and planet
- basically anything big and some thing that comes from it
- anything immutable that create mutable copies of itself

Here is where your company's branding/industry/voice can come into play.

E.g. if your company is called 'GoodBoy Comms', then you could use the analogy of a dog with a litter of puppies. Good design will help bake that into the product without being really crass/cheesy.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It is more of a template and instance relationship. Or to use object oriented programming terms, it is a class and instance relationship.

Comment: Indeed, but the problem is that users don't understand the relationship, so I am advocating a less technical analogy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the scenario, but is it *really* necessary to *name* them?

There are five ways to organize content - by Location, Alphabetical, Time, Category, and Hierarchy (or Magnitude)

If I print pages from a printer and they are all identical, then naming them is irrelevant, surely. What matters is which one I use and when. In which case an appropriate organization is by time - time modified, time created, time spent using - that kind of thing.

So rather than trying to identify things by an artificial ID or tag or reference, perhaps it's better to provide a flexible way of sorting items in a meaningful way. If there's really that many items, there will always just be 'the top few items' of interest given a sorted list - and then 'everything else'.